# Calibre on TrueNAS

Tags: calibre

I have setup Truenas scale 22.12.3.1 and I wanted to move my libraries to Truechart calibre app. So I setup the app with app storage 2 NFS Shares, 1 for Imports and 1 for Libraries. The NFS Share imports is mounted inside the container at /home/imports and the Libraries on /home/libraries. The plan was to transfer my Library backup inside the app and rebuild the Libraries. I transfered the .db files to the NFS share but when I try to restore my Libraries I get an error message that the .db files are corrupted. Looking further I see that they are not corrupted but I don't have permissions (Errno:13). I know that you will tell me I need to give more details but I am at a loss on what to tell. So please give some help or if someone has manage to setup calibre Truechart on Truenas any help will be welcomed.